# Get the Increment Id in to observer after saving the sales order?

Tags: magento

I am creating sales order in magento admin panel and I just wrote the following code in my **config.xml**

```
<global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <mymodule>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                        <method>handleOrder</method>
                    </mymodule>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_after>           
        </events>
    </global>
```

My observer file is as follows..

```
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer
{   
    public function handleOrder($observer)
    {

    }
}
```

In the above function I want to get the Increment Id of the sales order which invoked this function.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already assigned to the order at this point, so you can get it like this:

```
$incrementId = $observer->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
```

**Explanation:**

- The increment id gets assigned in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::_beforeSave()`
- "order" is a parameter of the event, so that you can use `$observer->getOrder()` which is actually a shortcut for `$observer->getEvent()->getData('order')`. The name of the parameter for the "before_save" and "after_save" events is defined in the `$_eventObject`  property of the model class:

  ```
  protected $_eventObject = 'order';
  ```

Comment: Hey If I want status of the order, what function is to be used.....`$observer->getOrder()->getStatus()` is not working.Thank you

Comment: ya If I echo $status it is printing "pending" but if I write this `$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO pp_sales_order VALUES ('','',?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$status);$status=$observer->getOrder()->getStatus();`,It is inserting `NULL`

Comment: Then the third column of your pp-sales-order table probably doesn't take strings. You shouldn't use raw SQL anyway, take advantage of Magento models instead

Answer (score 0):

I found it my self...

```
 $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                    ->setOrder('increment_id','DESC')
                    ->setPageSize(1)
                    ->setCurPage(1);

                $orderId = $orders->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();
                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
                $Incrementid = $order->getIncrementId();
```

The problem is solved.....

Comment: ... in the most overcomplicated way possible.